# Image Processing Outlines

Tags: python, arrays, image, processing

I'm writing a program that does basic image processing.

Keep in mind that the images are in grayscale, not RGB, also, I'm fairly new to Python, so an explanation of what I'm doing wrong/right would be incredibly helpful.

I'm trying to write an outline algorithm that follows this set of rules:

All light pixels in the original must be white in the outline image.
All dark pixels on the edges of the image must be black in the outline image.
If a pixel that is not on an edge of the image is dark and all of the 8 surrounding pixels are dark, this pixel is on the inside of a shape and must be white in the outline image.
All other dark pixels must be black in the outline image.

So far I have this:

```
def outlines(image):
    """
    Finds the outlines of shapes in an image.  The parameter must be
    a two-dimensional list of pixels.  The return value is another
    two-dimensional list of pixels which describes an image showing
    outlines of the shapes in the original image.  Each pixel in the
    return value will be either black (0) or white (255).
    """
    height=len(image)
    width=len(image[0])
    new_image=[]
    for r in range(height):
        new_row=[]
        index=0
        for c in range(width):
            if image[r][c]>128:
                new_row.append(255)
            if image[r][c]<=128:
                new_row.append(0])
        new_image.append(new_row)
```

Can someone show me how to implement the algorithm into my outlines function?

Thanks in advance.
Edit: This is an assignment for my University Comp Sci class, I'm not asking for someone to do my homework, rather because I've virtually no idea what the next step is. 
Edit2: If someone could explain to me a simple edge detection function that is similar to the algorithm I need to create I would appreciate it.

Comment: How does it "not work"?  Error message?  The image doesn't look like what you expected?

Comment: Well, so far you're just iterating through the image, and rounding off all pixels to either white or black. You aren't doing anything to detect outlines.

Comment: Some questions: 1) Is this homework ?. If yes you should tag as such. 2) why do you show the crop method ? is it of relevance for the question ? Please, clarify or delete it 3) what does it mean "STUDENTS: replace the following line with an implementation of this function" what function ?

Comment: So… This looks an awful lot like you're asking for someone to do your homework for you (as evidenced by the “STUDENTS: replace the following line with an implementation of this function” comment). That is generally frowned upon around here.

Comment: Please try to ask more specific questions (for example, your function is too slow and you want to speed it up, or you are getting a specific error) — these are fine, even if they are about homework.

Comment: A hint, appart from this question: if possible, install and use "pypy" instead of the standard Python for this kind of work - it's JIT optimizer can be up to 10 times faster for pixel algorithms than standard Python, keeping all the other advantages of working in Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to check if your pixel is dark or clear, you should also check, when dark, if the rest of pixels around are also dark in order to make that point white instead.

Check this function and try to use it for that purpose:

```
def all_are_dark_around(image, r, c):
    # range gives the bounds [-1, 0, 1]
    # you could use the list directly. Probably better for this especific case
    for i in range(-1,2):              
        for j in range(-1,2):
            # if the pixel is clear return False.
            # note that image[r+0][c+0] is always dark by definition
            if image[r+i][c+j] <= 128:  
                return False
    #the loop finished -> all pixels in the 3x3 square were dark
    return True
```

Advices:

1. note that you should never check `image[r][c]` when `r` or `c` are equal
   to `0` or to `height` or `width`. That is, when the checked pixel is in
   the border because in this case there is at least one side where
   there is no adjacent pixel to look at in the image and you will get
   an IndexError
2. don't expect this code to work directly and to be the best code on
   terms of efficiency or good style. This is a hint for your homework.
   You should do it. So look at the code, take your time (*optimally it
   should be equal or longer than the time it took to me to write the
   function*), understand how it works and adapt it to your code fixing
   any exceptions and border situations you encounter in the way.

Comment: Received: line 171, in are_all_dark_around
    if image[r+i,c+j] <= 128:  #is clear
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not tuple

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I'm now receiving: line 175, in all_are_dark_around
    if image[r+i][c+j] <= 128:
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: ask yourself why. print r+i and c+j. what happens? are you trying to check outside borders ? dont do it. set your ranges accordingly. At the end, make the borders black

Comment: @joaqin - are there any resources (packages, recommended reading) you'd recommend for someone to get up to speed in this field?

Comment: The basic package for image processing is [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). You can get more advanced functions with [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/intro.html). There is also [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/index.html) with a nice gallery of functions in its website.